# Stellar address prefix bitwise operator rationale

Tags: transactions, accounts, javascript-sdk

Stellar prefixes public keys with G. Why do they use a bitwise operation `VersionByteAccountID VersionByte = 6 << 3` to get the base 10 value 48? Javascript "[returns the default numerical values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)", so why not just use the base10 value of `VersionByteAccountID VersionByte = 48` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strkey format is a base32 encoding given by [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-6).  The first output character of the encoding is determined by the top five bits of the first byte.  So the value 6 is the value corresponding to 'G' in RFC4648, and it is shifted by 3 to make it the top five bits.

[Here's](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0011.md#strkey-format) a more complete specification of strkey format in a SEP.